# Iimplementing Classes into simple script

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a simple scripting exercise to calculate Car Insurance based off user input. I want to take this a step further by implementing classes into my script. I've tried watching a few videos and guides, but I'm not fully understanding the concept.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

The aim is to convert the current script into a Class called Quote which in-turn calculates the Car Insurance.

```
print("Hello")
print("Please enter your car insurance details:")
carMake = str(input("Enter your car make: "))
carModel = str(input("Enter your car model: "))
carType = str(input("Is your car type \"Sport\" or \"Family: \""))
engineSize = float(input("Enter your engine size in litres: "))
yearsClaimFree = int(input("Enter Years you have been claim free: "))
startingRate = 300

if engineSize >= 2.0:
    startingRate = startingRate * 2.5
elif engineSize >= 1.4:
    startingRate = startingRate * 1.5
else:
    print("Engine size is not effecting car insurance quote.")

if carType == "sport":
    startingRate = startingRate + 400
else:
    print("Car type is not effecting the car insurance quote.")

if yearsClaimFree >= 10:
    startingRate = startingRate - startingRate / 5
else:
    print("No discount gained from years claimed free.")

print("Your car insurance is €" + str(startingRate))
```

Comment: What have you tried doing and where is the problem?

Comment: See how to make a [mcve] in the [help].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1):

Your class should basically be a wrapper around some parameters used to generate a quote. (It's probably more appropriate as a simple function, but we'll go with it here.) All the user input will stay the way you currently have it, but the calculations for the rate will be done in a method. You'll *use* the class as follows; I leave implementing the class as an exercise.

```
print("Hello")
print("Please enter your car insurance details:")
car_make = str(input("Enter your car make: "))
car_model = str(input("Enter your car model: "))
car_type = str(input("Is your car type \"Sport\" or \"Family: \""))
engine_size = float(input("Enter your engine size in litres: "))
years_claim_free = int(input("Enter Years you have been claim free: "))

q = Quote(small_engine=1.4, medium_engine=2.0, claim_free=10, starting_rate=300)

quote = q.generate_quote(car_make, car_model, car_type, engine_size, years_claim_free)

print("Your car insurance is €{}".format(quote))
```

(Whether you define `generate_quote` to take the make and model is up to you;
nothing in your current script uses it, but `Quote` might have other methods
that would make use of that information. Or perhaps the starting rate could be a function of the make and model, rather than a single parameter.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that all you need is a function that takes `carMake`, `carModel`, `carType`, etc. and then contains all those `if` statements.  A class would come in handy if you want to input the all that data about the car and then call multiple different functions with that same data.

Here's how you would do it with functions:

```
def calcInsurance (make, model, type, engineSize, yearsClaimFree, startingRate):
    if engineSize >= 2.0:
        startingRate = startingRate * 2.5
    elif engineSize >= 1.4:
        startingRate = startingRate * 1.5
    else:
        print("Engine size is not effecting car insurance quote.")

    if carType == "sport":
        startingRate = startingRate + 400
    else:
        print("Car type is not effecting the car insurance quote.")

    if yearsClaimFree >= 10:
        startingRate = startingRate - startingRate / 5
    else:
        print("No discount gained from years claimed free.")
    print("Your car insurance is €" + str(startingRate))
```

Now if you want to have more functions that use the same data about the same car (`make`, `model`, `type`, `engineSize`, `yearsClaimFree`, and `startingRate`), then a class could be useful.

```
class Car:
    def __init__ (self, make, model, type, engineSize, yearsClaimFree, startingRate):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        # etc.
    def calcInsurance (self):
        # this function is exactly the same as I showed you before, except each of the car variables need to be preceded with self.

car = Car(...car_data...)
car.calcInsurance()
```

If you had more functions you wanted to do with the car, you could call them with the same data about this car just by using

```
car.calcInsurance()
car.doSomethingElse()
```

That is where using classes comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem, i'll give you what the class could look like this

```
class Quote:

def __init__(self, car_make, car_model, car_type, engine_size, years_claim_free, starting_rate):
    self.car_make = car_make
    self.car_model = car_model
    .....
    #you get the idea

def engine_size_impact_on_quote(self):
    #Your Code here and return something

def carType(self):
    #Evaluate car type

def calculate_insurance(self):
    #calculate insurance
    return self.starting_rate
#Create instance of the class
johns_quote = Quote(car_make, car_model...........)
johns_insurance = johns_quote.calculate_insurance()

print(f"John's Car insurance is {johns_insurance}"
```

When working with many arguments take a look at [kwargs or args](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html).

Python Classes can be a bit confusing, it took me a while before i could really understand them, there is a plethora of Python OOP tutorials